# React Form using Winterfell

Tags: reactjs, forms

I am having trouble using Winterfell to create a dynamic form.

https://github.com/andrewhathaway/Winterfell

http://winterfell.andrewhathaway.net/

I am trying to implement the basic login form but I am getting errors when on inspect. I have copied the schema and the js class. All I do is reference them in my App.js file.

form.js

```
import './SimpleForm.css';
var React = require('react');
var Winterfell = require('winterfell');
var loginSchema = require('./loginSchema');


class SimpleForm extends React.Component {
    render(){
        var onRender = () => {
            console.log('Great news! Winterfell rendered successfully');
        };

        var onUpdate = (questionAnswers) => {
            console.log('Question Updated! The current set of answers is: ', questionAnswers);
        };

        return(
            <div className="Sform">
                <Winterfell schema={loginSchema}
                    onRender={onRender}
                    onUpdate={onUpdate} />,
            </div>
        );

    }

}

export default SimpleForm;
```

The error occours any time I update a input field. The console.log statement for update never gets called. When I fill out the form in localhost, I get the following errors:

```
ReactBaseClasses.js:68 Uncaught TypeError: this.updater.enqueueCallback is not a function
at EmailInput.push.../../../node_modules/winterfell/node_modules/react/lib/ReactBaseClasses.js.ReactComponent.setState (ReactBaseClasses.js:68)
at EmailInput.handleChange (emailInput.js:99)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:144)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:193)
at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:243)
at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:258)
at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:615)
at executeDispatchesInOrder (react-dom.development.js:640)
at executeDispatchesAndRelease (react-dom.development.js:740)
at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (react-dom.development.js:753)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at forEachAccumulated (react-dom.development.js:718)
at runEventsInBatch (react-dom.development.js:896)
at runExtractedEventsInBatch (react-dom.development.js:906)
at handleTopLevel (react-dom.development.js:5074)
at batchedUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:18374)
at batchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:2299)
at dispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:5154)
at interactiveUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:18436)
at interactiveUpdates (react-dom.development.js:2320)
at dispatchInteractiveEvent (react-dom.development.js:5130)
```

I'm not sure what I am missing as I am just copying from a simple example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recommend you use that library it hasn't been updated in quite some time and doesn't work with React 16 https://github.com/andrewhathaway/Winterfell/issues/106

In fact it's not hard to do a form in React without any libraries I often wonder why people immediately turns to them. Try and make a login form using html inputs and `setState` for value changes (and html5 validation or else `setState` for error feedback) and you will see it's not hard :)

Here's a simple example to get you started:

```
class LoginForm extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
    email: '',
    password: '',
  };

  onFormSubmit = e => {
    const { email, password } = this.state;
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log({ email, password });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
        <input
          type="email"
          placeholder="Enter your email"
          onChange={e => this.setState({ email: e.target.value })}
          required
        />
        <input
          type="password"
          placeholder="Enter your password"
          onChange={e => this.setState({ password: e.target.value })}
          required
        />
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try to build a form by myself

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you